# syncing android database with server with intermittent internet conectivity

Tags: android

so I am writing an android app that will be used at a point of sale in some shops for survey questions. I have a java jsf web app using jpa with a mysql database that I want to sync with, preferably both ways but only a couple of tables. The android app will have only a few tables and will not replicate my server database completely.  Unfortunately the android apps will in some places have only intermittent internet access that will drop in and out.  I am currently looking at different options to use to store my data on android.  I have looked at:

1. writing my own sync between the database on my server and SQLite on android but there has to be an easier option
2. storing my data on app engine and syncing with app engine as per the example in the android developers guide however I am not sure how my limited internet connectivity will work
3. using couchdb but I dont really want to go down this route as I already have the server side set up

does anyone have any ideas?

can I store data locally using android then sync with app engine when I have a connection?

Thanks